# Excel for Mac - references in formula toolbar

Tags: microsoft-excel

My formula toolbar displays wrong - instead of for example showing in the cell where the formula is entered (A1 in this case )  =+B1+C1 it is almost like it is directing - it shows =+R1+R2.  So instead of using cell references it has a pathway to the cell. This makes it almost impossible to follow the logic of formulas in the formula bar. Is there I setting that is wrong? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have accidentally switched from A1 cell reference to R1C1 reference. Microsoft explains those concepts [right here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/about-cell-and-range-references-HP005198323.aspx).

To solve it (I'm using Excel for Mac menu style here) do the following:

- Go to the menu `Excel` and select `Preferences`
- Select the item `General` (first item)
- Uncheck the checkbox `R1C1 reference style`
- Click `OK` and things should be back to normal